# What event Listener to add to execute a section of code after page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a separate Javascript which is mentioned in the associated html under  tag. In the Javascript file, I've written a piece of code which until now gets executed when I click on a button. The code is enclosed as below:

```
document.getElementById('destination').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {//my code here});
```

Here 'destination' is the name of textbox.
However, I want to remove this textbox and button and execute that piece of code in something like:

```
document.addEventListener('load', (event) => {//my code here});
```

I have even tried to execute the code without adding event Listener to be executed synchronously. But I get some error on doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use something like:

```js
window.onload = () => {
//your code to run here
}
```

That's how I'd handle page loading events.

Answer (score 0):

`load` event is available on `Window` only, not on `Document`. What you're probably looking for is the `DOMContentLoaded` event which is fired as soon as the page has been parsed completely.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => { // your code here });
```

Use the `load` event if you want to wait for all the external resources, like images, stylesheets, etc. to finish loading first.

```
window..addEventListener('load', e => { // your code here });
```

You can attach a listener using the `onload` property as well.

```
window.onload = e => { // your code here };
```